# openGL: get coordinates after a glrotate

Tags: opengl, coordinate-transformation

I am trying to determine the coordinates after a glRotate.

Suppose we are initially at

```
 View.x = 0;
 View.y = 0;
 View.z = 10.0f;
```

And we do a glRotate

How do i get the new updated coordinates?

```
 View.x = ?;
 View.y = ?;
 View.z = ?;
```

This doesn't seem to work (what do I have wrong?):

```
    glRotatef(angle, x, y, z);

    GLfloat theMatrix[16];
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, theMatrix);

    viewX  = View.x * theMatrix[0] + View.y * theMatrix[4] + View.z * theMatrix[8];
    viewY = View.x * theMatrix[1] + View.y * theMatrix[5] + View.z * theMatrix[9];
    viewZ = View.x * theMatrix[2] + View.y * theMatrix[6] + View.z * theMatrix[10];
```

Comment: Have you heard of Rotation Matrices? Look it up on Wikipedia and you will understand what the result of a rotation is. Also please add the specific axis `[ex,ey,ez]` the `glRotate(angle,ex,ey,ez)` rotation you are using.

Answer (score 0):

glRotate modifies current modelView matrix... but all the transformations are performed inside the OpenGL pipeline, so you cannot easily get the updated results.

the simplest way is to multiply your vertex data by your rotation matrix. You can use glm library, some other library, or create own code for vector/vertex transformation.

if you want to get updated values for all the vertices you want to draw, then you can use some more advanced stuff like transform feedback

Comment: "performed on the GPU" Incorrect. Transformation are performed on OpenGL pipeline. Pipeline is not guaranteed to be on GPU. On old hardware it will be performed on CPU up to rasterization stage.