# Retrieve Vertex Coordinates

Tags: opengl-es, coordinates, vertex

My question is:

Is there a way to retrieve the coordinates of a vertex after translations or rotation?

Example: x = 10, y = 10, z = 0

After a series of calls to glTranslate or glRotate how can I know the actual status of x, y and z?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [openGL: get coordinates after a glrotate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543554/opengl-get-coordinates-after-a-glrotate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is not possible... opengl sends your vertex data to the GPU and only on GPU you can get them after the transformation.

to get transformed vertices you have to multiply them by the matrix on your own

```
for each vertex:
   vertex_transformed = matrix * vertex
```

in old OpenGL:

```
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, m);
x = pos.x*m[0] + pos.y*m[4] + pos.z*m[8] + m[12];
y = pos.x*m[1] + pos.y*m[5] + pos.z*m[9] + m[13];
z = pos.x*m[2] + pos.y*m[6] + pos.z*m[10] + m[14];
```

some more advanced ways is to use transform feedback and store those transformed vertices into a buffer (but still this buffer will be stored on the GPU).

Comment: ok but.. how can i retrieve the matrix, after transformations, using a gl method? and.. what is the math for multiply a matrix (float[16]) and a Vertex? ... for the transform feedback, how can i create this buffer to store progress?

Comment: no problem :) Transform feedback is a bit more advanced... I need some more experience with this, so I cannot explain it to you right now.